VS Code remote dev container using docker-compose and Dockerfile : cannot locate Dockerfile
I am trying to build the simplest remote dev container through VS Code using docker-compose and a Dockerfile.
.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
{
   "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yaml",
   "service": "devcontainer",
   "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces"
}

.devcontainer/Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xz-utils

.devcontainer/docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  devcontainer:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/workspaces:cached
    command: sleep infinity

However, it seems that Dockerfile cannot be located:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/xxxxxxxxx/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.389.0/Dockerfile'
Exit code 1
Command failed: /home/xxxxxxxxx/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40/server/node /home/xxxxxxxxx/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.389.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-89351ac2-59f5-41ee-8224-86d1d52b18711728981735033 --workspace-folder /home/xxxxxxxxx/develop/minidev --workspace-mount-consistency cached --gpu-availability detect --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/xxxxxxxxx/develop/minidev --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/home/xxxxxxxxx/develop/minidev/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/xxxxxxxxxe/develop/minidev/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration

I tried several different setups, but still have the error.

Docker-compose with an image (no Dockerfile) works
Dockerfile directly referenced in devcontainer.json without docker-compose works
The container builts successfully through docker-compose on the remote machine CLI
(Updated) I can build the container by directly using Dev Container CLI "devcontainer up --workspace-folder ." on the remote machine, so and replace Dockerfile by .devcontainer/Dockerfile in the docker-compose file which should not be requires as Dockerfile is in the same folder as docker-compose file.

If I look at the ~/.vscode-remote-container/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.389.0 folder on the remote machine, it only contains:
dist, package.json and scripts
Using VS Code 1.93.1 on Windows and dev containers extension 0.389.0 although earlier versions did not lead to better results. Podman version 5.1 or 5.2.3 installed on Linux remote host.
Did I do anything wrong here?
Workaround: After several attempts I replaced podman with Docker on the remote machine and it works now.
